# I'd like to see an alphabetized list of the people I've shared folders with.

Tags: google-drive

I share folders with cohorts of people. When I click advanced, shared with, it's impossible for me to tell if someone is missing from the list. Is there an easy way to alphabetize the list or extract the list so I can alphabetize it? I find myself re-adding an entire cohort instead of trying to sort through the list to see if someone is missing.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with Google Apps Script. Make a copy of the template below using **File > Make a copy.** You can run the script using the **Lookup** menu at the top and a folder ID.

### [Template Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wud65eVQ_eB09qeBA97hhFwlsFo7Opi6T2e58KYiSOA/edit?usp=sharing)

#### How it works

You can open a folder and grab information about it to write to a Google Sheet using apps script. Code is commented below. You can make a copy of the template linked above or copy and paste this into the script editor of your own sheet to run it.

```
function sharedFolderLookup() {
  // Open the Spreadsheet and UI controls for the prompt
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  // Get the folder ID to look for editors
  var id = ui.prompt("Enter the shared folder ID", ui.ButtonSet.OK).getResponseText();
  
  // Clear old data and write new headers
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Name", "Email"]);
  
  // Open the folder by ID and loop through editors.
  // Write their name and email into the spreadsheet.
  var editors = DriveApp.getFolderById(id).getEditors();
  for(var i=0;i<editors.length;i++) {
    var data = [
      editors[i].getName(),
      editors[i].getEmail()
    ];
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
}

// Create the custom menu item to run the script.
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu("Lookup")
    .addItem("Run", "sharedFolderLookup")
    .addToUi();
}
```

Once you've run the script, you can sort the names however you'd like and check for missing persons.